# Label display issue wtih Core Plot secondary axis

Tags: graph, core-plot, axis-labels

I have successfully created two series (one in each plot space) with each using its own scale.  I created the axes with this code:

```
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.hostView.hostedGraph.axisSet;
CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
CPTXYAxis *y2 = axisSet.yAxis;
y.plotSpace = plotSpace;
y2.plotSpace = plotSpace2;
graph.axisSet.axes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:x, y, y2, nil];
```

The code works correctly for setting the properties of y, but when the code reaches setting the properties for y2, such as:

```
y2.title = @"Velocity (m/s)";
```

y gets its title property changed.

Here is my plotspace setup:

> Blockquote

```
graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
graph.plotAreaFrame.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor clearColor]];
[graph addPlotSpace:plotSpace];

CPTScatterPlot *forcePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
forcePlot.dataSource = self;
forcePlot.identifier = CPDForce;
[graph addPlot:forcePlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
[graph addPlotSpace:plotSpace2];
CPTScatterPlot *velPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
velPlot.dataSource = self;
velPlot.identifier = CPDVelocity;
[graph addPlot:velPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace2];

[plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:forcePlot, nil]];
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(SlopeTime)];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(MaxForce+0.1*MaxForce)];

[plotSpace2 scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:velPlot, nil]];
plotSpace2.xRange = plotSpace.xRange;
plotSpace2.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(MaxVelocity+0.1*MaxVelocity)];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set `y` and `y2` to the same axis object. Create a new axis object for `y2` instead:

```
CPTXYAxis *y2 = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] init];
```